# PHP custom data service cache

Tags: php, json, caching, service

I need to implement a kind of a fast caching mechanism for a PHP application. It works something like this: Multiple node servers are requesting data from a central server (VIA JSON service). The node server should cache the responses on the file system in some fast efficient way. And that is the question - What will be the most optimal solution for the storage part. I  have some types - XML (heard it can be inefficient with many records), store array definition with content in a PHP file or just dump an array of records to a file. Which of these would be most efficient for that scenario? Or maybe something else? I need to note that it must be implementend on a clean PHP >=5.2 without any additional libraries nor SQL.

Comment: What will the data be used for on the node server? The quicker you write, the slower you read, so you have to make a trade off based on how much your writing and how much your reading, and of course what your doing with the data once its read out.

Comment: The node server will be a sort of CMS displaying the data to the end users. I want to minimise the lag on the first user request (when the cache on the node server is empty) so i think the writing should be as minimal as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the information you have provided, i would suggest simply dumping the JSON string to a file. This means there are no external libs or SQL engines required.

You could use XML if you want something that is "human readable" too, however XML isn't as quick and you would of course have to spend additional time generating the XML before you could store the data cache.

Reading is simply then just a case of getting the string from file and running through json_decode. If you only require parts of the data and not the entire lot, you could improve read performance by splitting the json object into blocks and writing to individual files, this trades off some of the write speed (not too much) but makes the read speed better.

Write speed could be made even better by writing to a partition configured with the ext2 filesystem.

However unless you working with large data sets and multiple cache files, there is no real reason to go to that sort of optimisation extent, writing the json to file as a string, and reading it back should be more than good enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't generate XML files for caching content for only one application. It's overhead generating and parsing the XML and it results in much more bytes required.

Generating PHP-files is effective but there are some issues with it:
 - possible parsing errors
 - Could cache data twice (Filesystem-Cache of OS + PHP-Opcode-Cache)

I would prefer to wrinting cache files as simple serialized PHP data because It has a low parsing semantic and is very effective. You can also speed-up it by using a binary serializer like igbinary or mgspack.

Btw: If you cache data from a remote service on different web-node I would recommend you to use a caching server like memcached ;)